# Moving MVC folders to root causing errors

Tags: model-view-controller, visual-studio-2017, file-move, sln-file

For version control I have moved all my projects folders from the myproject folder to the root where packages and myproject.sln reside and when I open myproject.sln I get 'One or more projects in the solution were not loaded correctly. Please see the Output Window for details'. I then tried opening myproject.csproj and the project opened but when I built it I get the error 'This project references Nuget package(s) that are missing on this computer'. I've tried editing myproject.sln and myproject.csproj but it still throws the same error.

[image]

What do I need to do to get the project to work with this layout?

Comment: move them back ..

Comment: Thanks Alexan, really helpful :-)

Comment: I feel your pain.... been there, done that, never want to do that ever again. 
In my case I had to go through both .csproj and .sln files as well and adjust all references to the "myproject\.." folder. If my memory doesn't fool me a lot of nuget references were having a bad hintpath. Also... look out for any references to "..\packages\.." and verify that the relative links are still correct

Comment: Thanks AardVark, that is so true, it has been painful but I didn't have a choice. If anyone has the same problem it's worth it in the end but as you say it involves extensive path editing and refreshing my Nuget packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed the issue by refreshing my Nuget packages and changing ..\packages to .\packages in the .csproj file. I also had to remove and re-install Newtonsoft.Json but it all works fine now.